# Blazor WebClient AddSingleton object cannot inject into C# class

Tags: c#, singleton, blazor-webassembly

I am new to Blazor technology. I am trying AddSingleton for a C# object and it is not working.

In my Blazor WebClient application I have C# class Student.cs like below

```
namespace MySampleWebClient
{
    public class Student
    {
        
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

In Program.cs

```
using MySampleWebClient;

Student myStudent = new Student()
{
    FirstName = "TEST First Name",
    LastName = "TEST Last Name"
};
builder.Services.AddSingleton(myStudent);
```

I have C# class StudentHandler.cs like below

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace MySampleWebClient
{
    public class StudentHandler
    {
        [Inject]
        protected Student StudentProperty { get; set; }
        
        private void GetStudent()
        {
            string firstName = StudentProperty.FirstName; //Here StudentProperty is NULL
            
        }
        
    }   
}
```

In _Import.razor I have like below

```
@using MySampleWebClient
```

But all looks good in Index.razor.cs like below

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace MySampleWebClient.Pages
{
    public partial class Index
    {
        [Inject]
        protected Student StudentProperty { get; set; }
        
        private void TestStudent()
        {
            string firstName = StudentProperty.FirstName; //All good here
            
        }        
    }   
}
```

**I donot know why I am unable to inject Student into StudentHandler.cs**

Answer (score 0):

It has already been documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0#use-di-in-services):

> Typically, this attribute isn't used directly. If a base class is
> required for components and injected properties are also required for
> the base class, manually add the [Inject] attribute:

......

> @inject (or the [Inject] attribute) isn't available for use in
> services. Constructor injection must be used instead. Required
> services are added by adding parameters to the service's constructor.
> When DI creates the service, it recognizes the services it requires in
> the constructor and provides them accordingly.

A related issue on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16294)

Comment: Why Inject works on Index.razor.cs but not in StudentHandler.cs .. I need to read the link you sent. Thanks